# Changing default focusable color of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview

How to change default focusable color(Orange) of `ExpandableListView`?

Anyone have any idea please share.

Comment: Have you checked the Android documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting android:listSelector to the color you want for focusable item.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I 'ListSelector' changes the whole list focus color on select but I  want to change just the the selected list item focus color not all.